# Build and aggregate time-series using Hive

Tags: hive

I am new to Hive and I have a table where the schema is:

```
Name, Count, Timestamp
```

I want to know if it is possible to write a query that will trigger an EMR job and extract/aggregate a list of count per name given an interval and a start/end epoch.

E.g.

Table content:

```
NameA, 1, 10000
NameA, 1, 2
NameA, 1, 1
NameB, 1, 500
NameB, 1, 1
```

Paremeters:

```
Interval: 1000ms
Start: 0
End: 10000
```

Output:

```
NameA, [2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
NameB, [2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the format *exactly* like that would be a little tricky, but something along the lines of...

```
SELECT
   name,
   round((timestamp - ${hiveconf:start})/${hiveconf:interval}) as interval_group,
   count(*) as interval_count
FROM source_table
WHERE timestamp >= ${hiveconf:start} and timestamp <= ${hiveconf:end}
GROUP BY name, round((timestamp - ${hiveconf:start})/${hiveconf:interval})
ORDER BY name, interval_group
```

You'll have to post-process to fill in the zeros for non-existent interval groups and format your output, but that should get you the data you need.